# config files of the Backup software

Tags: backup

I'm using Ubuntu's *Backup* (All Settings -> Backup).  I have a long list of excluded-folders I entered in it (in the *Folders* tab), which I want to copy somewhere else.

Where can I find the file this list is stored in?  (I'm assuming the list is stored in a text file somewhere, like ~/.backup/...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are stored in GSettings, like many settings in Ubuntu.  You can use the following command to see the list.

```
gsettings get org.gnome.DejaDup exclude-list
```